# Does REGEX_SUBSTR have a maximum return size in Snowflake?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does regex_substr in SNowflake (or in general) have a maximum return length or byte value? I have a very large field in a Snowflake table and I want to extract individual fields from it, for example

```
Name: TEST_MAIL

Email: TEST_MAIL@YAHOO.NOTREAL

Subject: iOS(2.7.04.1518): Unknown reason

Message: I can't enter 'SPECIFIC ROOM' because I'm too far away from the
reader. Can I have remote unlock permission?

Persistent State:
```

But when I try to extract the Message field using

```
SELECT 

--REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, '^(^Name\:)([A-z ])*') as Email_Name,
--REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, 'Subject\:([A-z0-9 \(\).])*') as Subject,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, 'Message\:([A-z0-9 \'.\?\n’,\)\(]*)') as Message
FROM TABLE
```

I get this

```
"Message: I can't enter 'SPECIFIC ROOM' because I'm too far away from the"
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the remaining content of this field is still enormous. It's stored in a TEXT field within Snowflake.

I do not have the ability to get those individual fields split out ahead of time by the client, nor can I get them reformatted into a JSON, although I have wondered if a better approach would be to somehow reformat the string so that all of the individual fields become their own json elements.

ANy help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use multiline [argument](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr#arguments) mode:

> String of one or more characters that specifies the regular expression parameters used to search for matches. The supported values are:
>
> c: case-sensitive.
>
> i: case-insensitive.
>
> m: multi-line mode.
>
> e: extract sub-matches.
>
> s: the ‘.’ wildcard also matches newline.

thus you will want to be using:

```
SELECT 

--REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, '^(^Name\:)([A-z ])*') as Email_Name,
--REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, 'Subject\:([A-z0-9 \(\).])*') as Subject,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, 'Message\:([A-z0-9 \'.\?\n’,\)\(]*)', 1, 1, 'ms') as Message
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I think you are on to something there, but it's not quite there.  It's still not matching, but the place where the return string seems to stop seems to be at a cr or something. It appears as a line break when the source is copied and pasted into a text editor.  Weird..

Comment: This works:
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, 'Message\:([A-z0-9 \'.\?\n\c\r’,\)\(]*)\n', 1, 1, 'ms') as Message

I had to add a \c\r to make it match the whole t hing

Thanks for your help.